# How to add free scrollbar to qlistwidget

Tags: c++, qt, qstring, qlistwidget

I search almost everywhere how to add verticalScrollBar to `QListWidget`, however I couldn't find suitable answer for my question.

I am trying to show output of `QProcess` to `QListWidget`. However there is no vertical scroll bar. In my example I have 200 line, but I can only see 5 line, because of there is no scroll bar. Here is what I tried;

```
    QString program = "ssh";
    QStringList arguments;
    arguments << "localhost" << "tail" << "-n" << "200" << "log.txt";

    QProcess *myProcess = new QProcess(this);
    myProcess->start(program, arguments);
    myProcess->waitForFinished();
    QString output(myProcess->readAllStandardOutput());

        QListWidgetItem *newItem = new QListWidgetItem;
        newItem->setText(output);
        ui->listWidget->insertItem(0, newItem);

        ui->listWidget->setMinimumWidth(ui->listWidget->sizeHintForColumn(0));

        ui->listWidget->verticalScrollBar()->width()`;`
```

Answer (score 1):

The Items in a `QListWidget` do not usually word-wrap, so you probably enabled word wrap using `setWordWrap(true)`.
Also, you can force a scrollbar to be visible using `setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOn)`.

Finally use `setVerticalScrollMode(QAbstractItemView::ScrollPerPixel)` so you can scroll through *single large* items. The default is `ScrollPerItem`, which is why you don't see any scrollbar: There is no need for one because the item is already in the viewport.